# "mvn test" did not execute @Mock annotated method

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a test class that looks like this:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public class SomeTest {
    @Mock
    Object someObj;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testNullPointer() {
        Mockito.when(someObj.toString()).thenReturn("1");
    }
}
```

When I run `mvn clean test` under the root directory of this project, it said that the testcase triggered`NullPointerException`, stack tree shows that `someObj` is null.
I was using `org.mockito::mockito-core::4.0.0` and `junit::junit::4.13.0`.
Seems like before() method is not executed. Any ideas why? Tks in advance.

Comment: Is that reproducible with just an `Object` class (instead of `SomeMapper`)?  I'm asking because it would be simpler for us to help you if so.

Comment: @AlexeyR. Yes it's reproducible. I have edited the code, hope it helps.

Comment: @AlexeyR. I found out that ```mvn test``` did not execute before() method, any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running this test you'll get this error above the stacktrace:

```
testNullPointer(org.example.SomeTest)  Time elapsed: 0.368 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

The interesting part here is the first bullet - you cannot stub the `hashCode` method. If you replace it by some method that can be stubbed, the test will pass. E.g.:

```java
Mockito.when(someObj.toString()).thenReturn("yay!");
```

Comment: Tks, that is a problem indeed. But another problem is that ```mvn test``` did not execute @Before method.

Comment: @theotheo When I run `mvn test` is most definitely executes the `@Before` method. Can you share your `pom.xml` file? Perhaps something there is not defined correctly.

Comment: I tried to add pom.xml but stackoverflow said that there are too many code. I was wondering if the surefire plugin was not configured right, ```org.apache.maven.plugins::maven-surefire-plugin::2.19```, with dependency ```org.apache.maven.surefire::surefire-junit3::2.19```

Comment: @theotheo definitely! You aren't using JUnit 3, you're using JUnit 4. IRC, you can just remove the dependency, maven-surefire-plugin should be able to handle JUnit 4 out of the box

Answer (score 0):

You are missing annotation on your class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeServiceTest {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sadly, the problem still exists.